# merge some columns in a pandas dataframe and duplicate the others

Tags: python, concatenation, python-polars

I have a similar problem to [how to select all columns from a list in a polars dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77982046/1711271), but slightly different:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import string

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
nr = 3
letters = list(string.ascii_letters)
uppercase = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
words, groups = [], []
for i in range(nr):
    word = ''.join([rng.choice(letters) for _ in range(rng.integers(3, 20))])
    words.append(word)
    group = rng.choice(uppercase)
    groups.append(group)
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a_0": np.linspace(0, 1, nr),
        "a_1": np.linspace(1, 2, nr),
        "a_2": np.linspace(2, 3, nr),
        "b_0": np.random.rand(nr),
        "b_1": 2 * np.random.rand(nr),
        "b_2": 3 * np.random.rand(nr),
        "words": words,
        "groups": groups,
    }
)
print(df)  
shape: (3, 8)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┬────────┐
│ a_0 ┆ a_1 ┆ a_2 ┆ b_0      ┆ b_1      ┆ b_2      ┆ words           ┆ groups │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---             ┆ ---    │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ str             ┆ str    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╪════════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 0.653892 ┆ 0.234362 ┆ 0.880558 ┆ OIww            ┆ W      │
│ 0.5 ┆ 1.5 ┆ 2.5 ┆ 0.408888 ┆ 0.213767 ┆ 1.833025 ┆ KkeB            ┆ Z      │
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 0.423949 ┆ 0.646378 ┆ 0.116173 ┆ NLOAgRxAtjWOHuQ ┆ O      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┴────────┘
```

I want again to concatenate the columns `a_0`, `a_1`,... into a column `a`,  columns `b_0`, `b_1`,... into a column `b`. However, unlike the preceding question, this time `a = [a_0;  a_1; ...]`. I.e., all the elements of `a_0` go first, followed by all the elements of `a_1`, etc. All the columns whose name doesn't end with a `_` followed by a digit (in this example, `words` and `groups`) must be duplicated enough times to match the length of `a`. Let `nr` and `nc` be the number of rows/columns in `df`. Then the output dataframe must have `m*nr` rows (`m=3` in this case) and `nc-2*(m-1)` columns, i.e.

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌─────────────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ words           ┆ groups ┆ a   ┆ b        │
│ ---             ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ str             ┆ str    ┆ f64 ┆ f64      │
╞═════════════════╪════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ OIww            ┆ W      ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.653892 │
│ KkeB            ┆ Z      ┆ 0.5 ┆ 0.408888 │
│ NLOAgRxAtjWOHuQ ┆ O      ┆ 1.0 ┆ 0.423949 │
│ OIww            ┆ W      ┆ 1.0 ┆ 0.234362 │
│ KkeB            ┆ Z      ┆ 1.5 ┆ 0.213767 │
│ NLOAgRxAtjWOHuQ ┆ O      ┆ 2.0 ┆ 0.646378 │
│ OIww            ┆ W      ┆ 2.0 ┆ 0.880558 │
│ KkeB            ┆ Z      ┆ 2.5 ┆ 1.833025 │
│ NLOAgRxAtjWOHuQ ┆ O      ┆ 3.0 ┆ 0.116173 │
└─────────────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980972/merge-groups-of-columns-in-a-polars-dataframe-to-single-columns/77982040#77982040) to your previous question by [@jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19355181/jqurious) to include *id_vars*, such as `words` and `groups`, as follows:

```py
(
    df
    .melt(id_vars=["words", "groups"])
    .with_columns(pl.col("variable").str.replace("_.*", ""))
    .with_columns(index = pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("variable"))
    .pivot(index=["index", "words", "groups"], columns="variable", values="value")
    .drop("index")
)
```

**Explanation**

Consider a simplified dataset with `n = 2` and just three `a_*` / `b_*` columns.

```
shape: (2, 8)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────────────┬────────┐
│ a_0 ┆ a_1 ┆ a_2 ┆ b_0      ┆ b_1      ┆ b_2      ┆ words            ┆ groups │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---              ┆ ---    │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ str              ┆ str    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════════════╪════════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 0.285304 ┆ 1.261851 ┆ 0.295949 ┆ VUvcCgzrycGaKSve ┆ I      │
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 0.460023 ┆ 1.89468  ┆ 1.042234 ┆ GXFVckCws        ┆ O      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┴────────┘
```

Using *id_vars* in the initial `pl.DataFrame.melt` adds the content of the `words` / `groups` columns to each row after the melt. We also ensure that the index column is created within each group defined by `words`, `groups`, and `variable`.

```py
(
    df
    .melt(id_vars=["words", "groups"])
    .with_columns(pl.col("variable").str.replace("_.*", ""))
    .with_columns(index = pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("variable"))
    .sort(["words", "groups", "variable"])
)

shape: (12, 5)
┌──────────────────┬────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ words            ┆ groups ┆ variable ┆ value    ┆ index │
│ ---              ┆ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str              ┆ str    ┆ str      ┆ f64      ┆ i64   │
╞══════════════════╪════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ GXFVckCws        ┆ O      ┆ a        ┆ 1.0      ┆ 0     │
│ GXFVckCws        ┆ O      ┆ a        ┆ 2.0      ┆ 1     │
│ GXFVckCws        ┆ O      ┆ a        ┆ 3.0      ┆ 2     │
│ GXFVckCws        ┆ O      ┆ b        ┆ 0.460023 ┆ 0     │
│ GXFVckCws        ┆ O      ┆ b        ┆ 1.89468  ┆ 1     │
│ GXFVckCws        ┆ O      ┆ b        ┆ 1.042234 ┆ 2     │
│ VUvcCgzrycGaKSve ┆ I      ┆ a        ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0     │
│ VUvcCgzrycGaKSve ┆ I      ┆ a        ┆ 1.0      ┆ 1     │
│ VUvcCgzrycGaKSve ┆ I      ┆ a        ┆ 2.0      ┆ 2     │
│ VUvcCgzrycGaKSve ┆ I      ┆ b        ┆ 0.285304 ┆ 0     │
│ VUvcCgzrycGaKSve ┆ I      ┆ b        ┆ 1.261851 ┆ 1     │
│ VUvcCgzrycGaKSve ┆ I      ┆ b        ┆ 0.295949 ┆ 2     │
└──────────────────┴────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

Then, the final pivot does no longer group by just `index` but also the `words` and `groups` columns.

Comment: I think `sort` messes things up. I'll edit my question to make it easier to double check the desired result.

Comment: yes, it looks like you need to remove the `sort`, and substitute it with a `.drop('index')`, in order to get the correct output

Comment: @DeltaIV I've included the `sort` to ensure that all elements of `a0` come before all elements of `a1`, etc. However, the `words` and `groups` columns were also sorted within these groups. Maybe this lead to the confusion. Glad its working now (I've also removed the `sort`).

Comment: thanks! It's better now. Last question: could you please explain what `index = pl.int_range(pl.len()).over(["words", "groups", "variable"])` does, and why is it needed?

Comment: @DeltaIV Sure! Without the `over(...)`, it would create a new integer column *index* that runs from 0 to length of the dataframe. However, by using `over(...)` we apply this to each group defined by *words*, *groups*, and *variable* separately, i.e. it creates a new integer column that within each group runs from 0 to length of group. It is needed as in the subsequent pivot operation, the value of in *variable* is used to create columns that are filled with the values in *value*. That is done separately for each group defined by the *index* argument ...

Comment: ... If we didn't include the *index* column in the *index* argument, there would be multiple values in some groups defined by the *index* argument and it is not clear what should happen (create multiple rows? aggregate the values?). Hence, with the *index* column, we enforce multiple rows in such cases of duplicate values.

Comment: Ah, I see now that using `pl.int_range(pl.len())` [is idiomatic in Polars to get an index](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.int_range.html), though [it's arguably not the best interface](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12420#issuecomment-1894235552). BTW, I found another way to perform this task which is shockingly faster than `melt`! See my new answer. Would love any comments

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, a simple `for` loop blows more idiomatic approaches out of the water, for what it concerns computational efficiency. Weird!

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import string
from time import perf_counter as pf

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
```

Generate a beefy dataframe:

```
s = pf()
nr = 100000
letters = list(string.ascii_letters)
uppercase = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
words, groups = [], []
for i in range(nr):
    word = ''.join([rng.choice(letters) for _ in range(rng.integers(3, 20))])
    words.append(word)
    group = rng.choice(uppercase)
    groups.append(group)
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a_0": np.linspace(0, 1, nr),
        "a_1": np.linspace(1, 2, nr),
        "a_2": np.linspace(2, 3, nr),
        "b_0": np.random.rand(nr),
        "b_1": 2 * np.random.rand(nr),
        "b_2": 3 * np.random.rand(nr),
        "words": words,
        "groups": groups,
    }
)
time = pf() - s
print(f'Time to build df: {time:.2f} seconds')
Time to build df: 19.582 seconds
```

`melt` + `pivot` as per @Hericks answer:

```
s = pf()
df1 = (
    df
    .melt(id_vars=["words", "groups"])
    .with_columns(pl.col("variable").str.replace("_.*", ""))
    .with_columns(index=pl.int_range(pl.len()).over(["words", "groups", "variable"]))
    .pivot(index=["index", "words", "groups"], columns="variable", values="value")
    .drop('index')
)
time = pf() - s
print(f'Time with melt + pivot: {time:.3f} seconds')
Time with melt + pivot: 0.660 seconds
```

Old-school `for` loop:

```
s = pf()
df_list = []
id_vars = ["words", "groups"]
m = int((len(df.columns) -len(id_vars))/2)
for n in range(m):
    tmp = df.select(id_vars)
    tmp = tmp.with_columns(
        df[f'a_{n}'].alias('a'),
        df[f'b_{n}'].alias('b'),
    )
    df_list.append(tmp)
df2 = pl.concat(df_list)
time = pf() - s
print(f'Time with for loop: {time:.3f} seconds')
Time with for loop: 0.011 seconds
```

Check that the two dataframes are equal, just in case:

```
df1.equals(df2)
True
```

A speedup of 60x!

Comment: The `over` only needs to be on the "name" i.e. `.over("variable")` in this case. The for loop example hardcodes `range(3)` - the reason for the melt / pivot pattern was that it does not require this, nor does it require that all names have the same `_N` suffixes.

Comment: All the columns have the `_\d` suffix, which makes it very easy not to hardcode the `3`: see new code. If this wasn't true, then the melt/pivot pattern would indeed be required.

Comment: Yeah, you could also adapt the code to handle different suffixes too. The reason I posted the melt + pivot approach was that I find it *"simpler to write"* instead of the boilerplate code - so thought it was worth sharing. I'm not exactly sure if it counts as idiomatic, and it is computationally more expensive due to the double reshape.